# How to print the number of locations of file found

Tags: shell

Prompt the user for a file name, without the path (Ex: xyz.out)
- Using the find command, provide the full path to the file
- At the end, “print number of locations of that file found”
- If it’s not found, then display “not found

and this is my script

```
#! /bin /bash

echo "please enter your file name"
read filename

if [ -f $filename ];
then
    echo "file $filename found"
    find $PWD -type f | grep $filename
    #find "$(cd ..; pwd)" -name $filename
else
    echo "file $filename was not found"
fi
```

but the thing is At the end, i need to “print number of locations of that file found”
help me out with this

Comment: Using `grep` like that means you will also, incorrectly, find files called `FileWith-xyz.out-InTheMiddle`

Comment: When you say *"full path"*, do you mean the *"absolute path"* which always starts from the root of the filesystem with `/`, or do you mean the *"relative path"* which starts at the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this to get the count:

```
find $PWD -type f  -name $filename 2>/dev/null | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
find "$PWD" -type f  -name "$fname" |grep "" -c
```

Answer (score 0):

In trying to keep it as short as possible, one approach with Posix shell would be to fill a temporary file with the file names returned by `find`, `cat` the file to provide your output, and use `wc` to provide the line count (note: you use your own pattern instead of `"*cmpf*"` shown below):

```
$ find . -name "*cmpf*" -printf "%P\n" >tmp; cat tmp; c=$(wc -l <tmp); \
rm tmp; printf "[%s] files found\n" $c
cmpf1f2.c
cmpf1f2_2.c
bin/cmpf1f2_2
bin/cmpf1f2
snip/cmpf1f2_notes.txt
cmpf1f2_for.c
[6] files found
```

If bash is available, another approach is to read the matching files into an array and then use the number of elements as your count. Example:

```
$ a=( $(find . -name "*cmpf*" -printf "%P\n") ); printf "%s\n" ${a[@]}; \
printf -- "--\n'%s' files found.\n" ${#a[@]}
cmpf1f2.c
cmpf1f2_2.c
bin/cmpf1f2_2
bin/cmpf1f2
snip/cmpf1f2_notes.txt
cmpf1f2_for.c
--
'6' files found.
```

Both approaches give you both the files and directories in which they reside as well as the count of the files returned.

**Note:** if you would like `./` before each file and directory names, use the `%p` format instead of `%P` above.